# JSON normalize pandas column without losing index

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've got a dataframe as in the image:

[image]

I'd like to transform that into a dataframe similar to the following:

[image]

But, in the second image, instead of having (0,1,2...) as index, I want to keep card_id as index - or as a column, whatever.

The second image is obtained applying `pd.json_normalize` in the first df's `card_fields` column.

I did find something similar in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872676/how-to-keep-the-index-of-my-pandas-dataframe-after-normalazation-json), but in there we start with a dictionary, instead of a dataframe, as in my case, so the proposed solution is not  directly translatable to my case without doing a lot of manipulation.

Comment: `pd.concat([df.reset_index()[['card_id']], pd.json_normalize(df['card_fields'])], axis=1])`

Answer (score 3):

try `pd.json_normalize(df['card_fields']).set_index(df.index)`?
df is the dataframe from image 1.

Comment: That was my first try, even before asking the question. Unfortunally, seems like ```pd.json_normalize``` doesn't preserve order, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @DaviAlefe i think `json_normalize` is preserving the order. are you sure it doesn't?

Comment: yes, it definitely preserves order